Why am I unable to to login to my React web app on a mobile device but am able on desktop?
I have delployed a web app which allows users to register and login on a desktop/ laptop device but I am unable to login as a user on a mobile device, the front-end is built with React and the back-end API using Django Rest Framework.
I think my API setting are correct;
Django API

settings.py;

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "https://pinch-5e6e24dd12fc.herokuapp.com"
]

REST_AUTH = {
    'USE_JWT': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_HTTPONLY': False,
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'auth-token',
    'JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE': 'refresh-token',
    'JWT_AUTH_SECURE': True,
    'JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE': 'None',
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'pinch_api.serializers.CurrentUserSerializer',
}

views.py;

from .settings import REST_AUTH
JWT_AUTH_COOKIE = REST_AUTH['JWT_AUTH_COOKIE']
JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE = REST_AUTH['JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE']
JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE = REST_AUTH['JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE']
JWT_AUTH_SECURE = REST_AUTH['JWT_AUTH_SECURE']
USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER = ['pinch_api.serializers.CurrentUserSerializer']


@api_view()
def root_route(request):
    return Response({
        "message": "Welcome to the Pinch API"
    })


@api_view(['POST'])
def logout_route(request):
    response = Response()
    response.set_cookie(
        key=JWT_AUTH_COOKIE,
        value='',
        httponly=True,
        expires='Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT',
        max_age=0,
        samesite=JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE,
        secure=JWT_AUTH_SECURE,
    )
    response.set_cookie(
        key=JWT_AUTH_REFRESH_COOKIE,
        value='',
        httponly=True,
        expires='Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT',
        max_age=0,
        samesite=JWT_AUTH_SAMESITE,
        secure=JWT_AUTH_SECURE,
    )
    return response

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'https://pinch-api-f947cf5f7bdc.herokuapp.com',
]

React

axiosDefault.js;
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://pinch-api-f947cf5f7bdc.herokuapp.com/';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

export const axiosReq = axios.create(); 
export const axiosRes = axios.create();

export const loginUser = async (signInData) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("/dj-rest-auth/login/", signInData);
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error.response?.data || error;
    }
  };

I have tried signing in on different browsers on mobile, but this still does not work.
The authentication request might be succeeding in the API, but there could be an issue with handling the login state or redirecting after login.
It seems like on mobile, even though the sign-in accepts the login credentials, it is unable to create a token/ session as the session storage and local storage is empty when attempting to sign-in.
Would anybody have any ideas or tips how I can fix the issue please?
Thank you :)

It's not clear what's happening here, but can you try connecting your real mobile device to your PC and debug these cases via chrome://inspect/#devices?
By doing this you will be able to understand the issue in your app
